# onPageFinished Javascript WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I feel pretty stupid for having to ask this but I can't for the life of me get it to work.

So I've searched around and found lots of help, guides, and etc for using the onPageFinished function in WebViewClient and my code is largely based on these.

Basically I have a function that is supposed to load a web page and then hides certain elements on that page with the onPageFinished. Instead of actually doing this though it hides the entire page and the webview displays the text "none".
When I comment out the onPageFinished function the webview loads the page just fine which leads me to believe that it has to be the javascript but according to the w3c site my javascript is correct for what I want to do...

So my question is this, Does anyone see the problem with the below code and/or anyone have a suggestion for something else that might accomplish my above stated goals?

Any help in getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private WebView browser;
    private String url = "https://www.google.com";

    < onCreate calls cleanPage and other stuff >

    public void cleanPage() {
        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                browser.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('lga').style.display='none';");
            }
        });
        browser.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Notes:

-The above uses google as an example, lga is the id of the google banner div.

-browser and url are global because once I get cleanPage working I will add in other functions that will alter them as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `void(0);` at the end of your `javascript:` URL. Otherwise, WebView replaces your current page with the result of the JS evaluation (in your case, that is the string `"none"`).

So change this:

```
browser.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('lga').style.display='none';");
```

to:

```
browser.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('lga').style.display='none';void(0);");
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!! (If I could up vote your answer I would.)

Comment: i have JS which works on webview first time but it didn`t works second time "var divs = document.getElementsByTagName(\"div\");for (var i = 0; i < divs.length ; i++) {var status = divs[i].getAttribute(\"class\");if ( status.includes(\"gemini\") ) { divs[i].style.display='none';}}